# Different ways to define models in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, database, orm, model, sequelize.js

**The Motivation:**

I'm in the process of researching `Sequelize` and thinking about building a [`ESLint`](http://eslint.org/) plugin to catch common `Sequelize`-specific code style violations (that can be catched statically, of course).

One of the rules I'm thinking to implement (thanks to [@janmeier](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6111)) is to *enforce having `type` for every model field*. From what I understand, [`define()`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model) is a very common way to define a model:

```
sequelize.define('Locale', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    locale: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

**The Question:**

Are there any *other ways* to define a model and its fields in `Sequelize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of the static code analysis utility I've started to build, I assume the `define()` method is always used to define the models.

The only thing you should take into account is that there are *2 general ways to define model fields*:

- *implicit*, short version:

  ```
  sequelize.define('Locale', {
      locale: DataTypes.STRING
  });
  ```
- *explicit*, longer, but more extensible and readable ("Explicit is better than implicit"):

  ```
  sequelize.define('Locale', {
      locale: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
      }
  });
  ```

The longer syntax also helps when additional options like `defaultValue` or `unique` are needed to be specified on a model field.

What actually helped me to get a better understanding how to define and organize `Sequelize` models, was the [`Sequelize` tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W_dd3uA1Iw) series by Code Cast.